# Confusion with distinct and indistinct object

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nscountedset

I thought that `NSCountedSet` counted `numB` and `numC` twice in the frequency because they had the same value, so I created two `Fraction` objects (not shown) from my class `Fraction`, and I set their `ivars` (`numerator`, `denominator`) to equal each others but the `countForObject:` treated them as two distinct objects and counted their frequencies as one each. `numA` and `numB` pointed to different places in memory but share the same value, and the two `Fraction` objects pointed to different places in memory but shared the same value. Why were the `Number` objects treated as indistinct, but not the `Fraction` objects?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Fraction.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSNumber *numA = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1];
        NSNumber *numB = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2];
        NSNumber *numC = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2];

        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: numA, numB, numC, nil];

        NSCountedSet *mySet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray: array];
        for (NSNumber *myNum in mySet) {
            NSLog(@"Number: %i Frequency: %lu", [myNum intValue], [mySet countForObject: myNum]);
        }

        }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
2012-08-05 17:44:58.667 prog[1150:707] Number: 1 Frequency: 1
2012-08-05 17:44:58.669 prog[1150:707] Number: 2 Frequency: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your custom class to be recognized by `NSCountedSet` and by the rest of Foundation, you must implement `-isEqual:` and `-hash` correctly. By default, they compare pointers, so two objects will never compare equal even if they represent the same data. A naïve implementation of `-isEqual:` for a `Fraction` class would probably look like this:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual: (id)anObject {
    #error Naive implementation. Do not use.
    if (anObject == self) {
        return YES;
    } else if ([anObject isKindOfClass: [Fraction class]]) {
        Fraction *reducedSelf = [self reducedFraction];
        Fraction *reducedOther = [anObject reducedFraction];
        if (reducedSelf.numerator == reducedOther.numerator && reducedSelf.denominator == reducedOther.denominator) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
    #error Naive implementation. Do not use.
    Fraction *reducedSelf = [self reducedFraction];
    return reducedSelf.numerator ^ reducedSelf.denominator;
}
```

Note that this would not allow you to compare instances of your `Fraction` class against instances of `NSNumber`. Because `-isEqual:` *must* be commutative and because equal objects *must* have the same hash value, you would need to provide an implementation that was compatible with `NSNumber` (probably by subclassing it and using `NSNumber`'s implementations.)